# Vb macro excel 2007 hide rows if cell equal zero

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a macro on a table which is part of a sheet , it goes from A18 to J33, the 18th row is the header. 
The macro should hide the rows that has zero in the J column cells.

Please help!!!!!!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you see your spreadsheet hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>. This will open VBE (visual basic editor) for you.

right-click in the `VBA Project Explorer` (if you can't see it then click View -> Project Explorer or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

Insert a Module

[image]

Copy and paste the below code

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("J19:J33")
        If Not isEmpty(cell) Then
            If cell.Value = 0 Then 
                cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the macro.

before

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: Thank u and sorry i am illiterate when it comes to vb macros , its not working  highlighting in red: For Each cell In.  And giving compile error: synthax error

Comment: have you copied and pasted as is? where did you paste the code to?

Comment: @mehow: The above code will hide blank `J` cells as well. You m ight want to change it to `If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Value = 0 Then` ?

Comment: BTW congrats on 5k ;)

Comment: youre right @SiddharthRout I forgot about the empty rows and didnt mention the code was not tested yet.

Comment: + 1 Works as expected :)

Comment: @PettyBathishJreish just copy and paste the code as is. Do not modify anything. It works for me and Sid so I have no idea why it doesnt work for you :/

Comment: Ok it works now. . . Actually cuz i was asking on my phone earlier and the excel is ob my pc. . . Thank u

Comment: How can i add a button that triggers the macro?